# Fact table that has 2 date columns (OrderDate and ShipDate) how to present it in Matrix view

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, dashboard

I have a fact table that has 2 date columns in PowerBI.

I want to create a Matrix view that looks like below:

I was able to achieve the below table which is not what I want:

Answer (score 0):

Closest output to your desired is available be using Calendar Table (Date in my example), and measures. We need two relationship between orders nad Calendar.

[image]

```
CountShipDate = CALCULATE( countrows( Orders ), USERELATIONSHIP(Orders[ShipDate],'Date'[Date]) )
```

Matrix:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback. The solution you provided is close to what I want to achieve. Do you have an idea of how I can get "True" and "False" to be colums under "CountOfOrderDate" and "CountOfShipDate"?

Comment: I don't know a ready-made solution. I would try to prepare an additional, auxiliary table with labels + IF logic